Identity in Clean Architecture. Unable to find the required services,required services by calling 'IServiceCollection.AddRazorPages'
I am new to Netcore and Clean Architecture. I have do many search but many thing change so I decide to ask here.
I also post the source code here for more investigation.
https://github.com/nguyentuananh921/MyCA2024
At First I creat the MVC with Authentication and Everything find.
Then I want to move Identity to Infastructure Identity.
I create new dbcontext IdentityDataBaseContext in Infastructure.Identity project.
And I Create IdentityServiceDependentInjection to register Dependent Injection
First Problem is that
In IdentityServiceDependentInjection I have error with
services.AddDefaultIdentity(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
So I Change to
services.AddIdentityCore()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores();
And Now I got the error
Unable to find the required services. Please add all the required services by calling 'IServiceCollection.AddRazorPages' inside the call to 'ConfigureServices(...)' in the application startup code.'
